# Issues calling a Batch File through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm having some issues when trying to call a batch file through PowerShell. When I run the batch file itsel, everything works fine; below is my PS Code

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Source\BuildSource\SATCOM\EBEM\LCT GUI 02.01.04\run_ebem_lct_020104.bat"
```

Below is my batch file

```
@title EBEM LCT 02.01.04
PathTemp=%Path%
# Path=C:\Program Files\jre7\bin;%Path%
Path=C:\Program Files\jre7\bin;%Path%
start javaw -classpath .\EBEM_LCT_020104.jar;comm.jar ebem_lct.system.LCT_Client Path=%PathTemp% PathTemp= exit
```

and finally, below is what PS is spitting back to me

```
C:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\PowerShell>PathTemp=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\;C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\;C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\Win64\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Source\TDC-Certs\TDC-Certs\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\localadmin\.dotnet\tools
'PathTemp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\PowerShell># Path=C:\Program Files\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\;C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\;C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\Win64\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Source\TDC-Certs\TDC-Certs\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\localadmin\.dotnet\tools
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\PowerShell>Path=C:\Program Files\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\;C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\;C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\Win64\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Source\TDC-Certs\TDC-Certs\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\localadmin\.dotnet\tools
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **No need to use `cmd /c` to invoke a batch file from PowerShell**; just invoke it *directly*, which in the case of a *quoted* batch-file path requires use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).
- Your batch file:

  - is missing `@echo off` to suppress echoing the commands before they're being executed
  - mistakenly tries to set environment variables without the `SET` command
  - mistakenly tries to use `#` to initiate a line comment.

In general, it looks like the code was copied from a *Bash* shell script and poorly adapted for `cmd.exe`.

Invocation from PowerShell:

```
& "C:\Source\BuildSource\SATCOM\EBEM\LCT GUI 02.01.04\run_ebem_lct_020104.bat"
```

Fixed batch-file content:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Set the window title - this will revert when the batch file exits,
:: so there is little point in doing this, given that `start` below
:: launches the application *asynchronously* and the batch file therefore
:: exits quickly.
title EBEM LCT 02.01.04

:: Temporarily add a folder to the PATH.
:: Thanks to `setlocal`, there is no need to restore the previous path afterwards.
Set "Path=C:\Program Files\jre7\bin;%Path%"

:: Start the application
start javaw -classpath .\EBEM_LCT_020104.jar;comm.jar ebem_lct.system.LCT_Client
```

The **alternative** is to make do without a batch file altogether, and **do it all in PowerShell**:

```
# Save the previous $env:Path value and temporarily prepend a new folder.
$prevPath, $env:Path = $env:Path, "C:\Program Files\jre7\bin;$env:Path"

# Invoke the (GUI) application, which launches asynchronously.
javaw -classpath .\EBEM_LCT_020104.jar;comm.jar ebem_lct.system.LCT_Client

# Restore the original $env:Path value.
$env:Path = $prevPath
```

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @RyanFitzgerald. Indeed, you don't really need a batch file for this, but note that your solution doesn't restore the previous `$env:Path` value - please see my update for how to do that.